# Update state after using dispatch

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Im using vuex and I have an `action`

```
storeExpense(context, params){
    axios.post('api/expenses', params)
    .then( response => {
        console.log("Expense Created");
    })
    .catch( error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

and on my Expense.vue im using the action via

```
this.$store.dispatch('storeExpense',this.expense)
.then( response => {
   this.modalShow = false
   this.$swal(
   'Success',
   'Expense has been created!',
   'success'
   )
})
```

I dont have an error but after the expense was created the state is not updating therefore I need to refresh the page in order for my table to get the latest data.

I have a mutation called

```
mutateExpenses(state, payload){
 state.expenses = payload
}
```

however when i use this after the response it overrides the whole state.expenses object to a single object because this.expense is a single object

Im new to vuex.

Comment: Your action should be committing mutation(s) to update your store with the API response. You should do it where you logged "Expense Created".

Comment: edited sir ....

Comment: Your action doesn't return a Promise (and shouldn't), I don't understand the `then` after the `dispatch`. You should also call your mutation in place of your `console.log("Expense Created");`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must update your store using mutations that are called inside your actions.
I suggest you to dive a bit into the [Vuex documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html), especially the mutations and actions :)

Here is an example of how to use the store :

It goes *dispatch* --> *action* --> *mutation*

```js
// Your store
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    posts: [],
    isLoading: false
  },

  mutations: {
    // Must be called by actions AND ONLY by actions
    add(state, post) {
      // Add the given post to the 'posts' array in our state
      Vue.set(state.posts, state.posts.length, post)
    },
    busy(state) {
      Vue.set(state, 'isLoading', true)
    },
    free(state) {
      Vue.set(state, 'isLoading', false)
    }
  },
  actions: {
    create({
      commit
    }, post) {
      commit('busy')
      axios.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', post)
        .then(response => {
          // Call the mutation method 'add' to add the newly created post
          commit('add', response.data)
        })
        .catch((reason) => {
          // Handle errors
        })
        .finally(() => {
          commit('free')
        });
    },
  }
})

// Your Vue app
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  store,
  data: {
    post: {
      title: 'foo',
      body: 'bar',
      userId: 1
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onButtonClicked() {
      this.$store.dispatch('create', this.post)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.1.0/vuex.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="onButtonClicked">Create Post</button>
  <div>Posts : <span v-if="$store.state.isLoading">Requesting</span></div>
  <div v-for="post in $store.state.posts">
    {{post}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. at first i was using push function to append the data on the array. didnt know that it will not work. Vue.set is what i am looking for thanks